# Why the use of `,@` does not work as I expected in this common lisp macro? Why is Slime returning this error message?

Tags: macros, stack, common-lisp

I am reading the book **Lisp** written by Winston. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

In chapter 8 (about macros), the book has the following exercise:

> Problem 8-7: A stack is  a learnly ordered set of things that can be accessed using push and pop operations. OUR-PUSH adds a new item to the top of the stack, while OUR-POP removes the item on top of the stack. A list can be used to represent a stack, with the first element corresponding to the item on top. Define OUR-PUSH and OUR-POP as macros. OUR-PUSH takes two arguments, the item to be pushed and the name of a variable whose value it the list representing the stack. The value returned is the enlarged list. OUR-POP takes a single element, the name of the variable whose value is in the list. The value returned is the item popped. In both cases the value of the variable is changed to reflect the new state of the stack.

I got it correct for the `pop` function. However, I had a trouble with the `push` re-implementation. This is the answer-sheet:

```lisp
(defmacro book-our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setq ,stack (cons ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
```

It works as expected. My initial answer was similar:

```lisp
(defmacro our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setf ,stack (list ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
```

But this generates an accidental **list nesting** such as:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defparameter so-stack '(3 4 5 6))
SO-STACK

CL-USER> so-stack
(3 4 5 6)

CL-USER> (our-push 2 so-stack)
(2 (3 4 5 6))
```

Then, I thought: "Oh, this must the kind of situation in which you use `,@`". Because `,@` creates a splicing behavior. Thus, I did:

```lisp
(defmacro our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setf ,stack (list ,item-to-be-pushed ,@stack)))
```

However, it **does not** work. Moreover, Slime throws an error message that feels weird to me:

```lisp
The value
  SO-STACK
is not of type
  LIST
```

Specially because:

```lisp
CL-USER> (listp so-stack)

T
```

Is there a way to use `,@` for this situation?
Why is slime indicating the variable `so-stack` is **not** a list when it actually is one?

Comment: The symbol `so-stack` is not a list. `(listp 'so-stack)` -> `NIL`

Comment: Please replace the picture with text - this would make your question searchable and thus more useful. Thank you.

Comment: @sds, this is not a regular pdf. It is a scanned pdf. The book pages behave as images. Thus, I would need to manually re-type everything.

Comment: @PedroDelfino: c'est la vie.

Comment: It's not that much to type, is it?

Comment: @Manfred, not that much. I feel lazy sometimes, though haha. I have already replaced the picture with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are at the worng level.  When the macro is expanded using its macro function, you are operating on the *source code*.

The source code is this *list*:

```lisp
(my-push thing foos)
```

i. e. a list with three *symbols*, named `my-push`, `thing`, and `foos`.

The macro function takes this list and transforms it to a different list, in your case:

```lisp
(setf foos (list thing foos))
```

This is then compiled further (more macro expansions, finally compilation to machine code).

If you try to splice `foos` that's impossible, because a symbol is not a list.

The macro function never sees what these symbols mean.  It is finished before the form even gets compiled to machine code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer-sheet:

```
(defmacro book-our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setq ,stack (cons ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
```

As you say, your initial answer was similar:

```
(defmacro our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setf ,stack (list ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
```

And, intrinsically, that's the problem. `cons` is like a tube of glue - it sticks a value onto an existing list. `list` is just a big sack that I can put stuff into.

```
(list 5 '(1 2 3 4)) ; puts 5 and '(1 2 3 4) into a single list, side by side
                    ; => (5 (1 2 3 4))

(cons 5 '(1 2 3 4)) ; attaches 5 to list '(1 2 3 4)
                    ; => (5 1 2 3 4)
```

Usually, you use list - just not in this case.

Then you attempted to splice the values together using `@`. It didn't work.

```
(defmacro our-push-splice (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setf ,stack (list ,item-to-be-pushed ,@stack)))
```

The best way to find out why it didn't work is to use macro-expand-1. This shows what the macro is actually doing, not what it ought to do.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter stack '(1 2 3 4))
STACK
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(our-push 5 stack))
(SETF STACK (LIST 5 STACK))
T
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(our-push-splice 5 stack))
(SETF STACK (LIST 5 . STACK))
T
CL-USER> (our-push 5 stack)
(5 (1 2 3 4))
CL-USER> (our-push-splice 5 stack)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: LIST datum: STACK>.
```

So, the attempt at splicing fails, as it seems that it was expected that the stack would be spliced in when the macro was evaluated. The name is inserted, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Svante's answer is correct: macros are functions which transform *source code*.  But sometimes it's useful to see this by making macros print what they are doing.  Here is a simple hack to do this (a much more general hack by someone else is [here](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#tracing-macroexpansion-trace-macroexpand)).

```
(defmacro define-traced-macro (name args &body forms)
  ;; Define a traced macro.  This probably misses edge cases
  `(progn
     (defmacro ,name ,args ,@forms)
     (let ((m (macro-function ',name)))
       (setf (macro-function ',name)
             (lambda (form environment)
               ;; Do it like this so we get the source form even if
               ;; the macro fails
               (let ((*print-pretty* t))
                 (format *trace-output* "~&~S~%" form))
               (let ((*print-pretty* t)
                     (expansion (funcall m form environment)))
                 (format *trace-output* "~& -> ~S~%" expansion)
                 expansion))))
     ',name))
```

And now if you define a macro with `define-traced-macro` rather than `defmacro` it will trace its expansion:

```
(define-traced-macro book-our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setq ,stack (cons ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
```

```
> (let ((x '(1 2)))
    (book-our-push 3 x)
    x)
(book-our-push 3 x)
 -> (setq x (cons 3 x))
(3 1 2)
```

This should convincingly show why your version can't work.

---

As an aside, once you have `define-traced-macro` you can use it to redefine itself (to do this seriously you'd want to define it by hard-wiring its own expansion into the source):

```
> (define-traced-macro book-our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
    `(setq ,stack (cons ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
(define-traced-macro book-our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
  `(setq ,stack (cons ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
 -> (progn
      (defmacro book-our-push (item-to-be-pushed stack)
        `(setq ,stack (cons ,item-to-be-pushed ,stack)))
      (let ((m (macro-function 'book-our-push)))
        (setf (macro-function 'book-our-push)
              (lambda (form environment)
                (let ((*print-pretty* t))
                  (format *trace-output* "~&~S~%" form))
                (let ((*print-pretty* t)
                      (expansion (funcall m form environment)))
                  (format *trace-output* "~& -> ~S~%" expansion)
                  expansion))))
      'book-our-push)
book-our-push
```

This is entertaining, if that's the sort of thing you are entertained by.